Passing a large object to async task in C++
I have program that receives callback calls from a library when messages are received. The callbacks' signature is void on_message(const MyLargeObject &my_large_object);
My code for reacting to some of the messages is more complex than what I want to run directly in the callbacks. Because of that, I am launching an asynchronous task (std::async) to do the actual processing.
Currently, the asynchronous tasks' signature is void on_message_async_task(MyLargeObject my_large_object);. My reasoning says that I should pass the argument to the async task as a copy because I see no guarantee that the original object lives until the task is finished. Static code analysis is, however, saying that I should use const reference instead to avoid expensive copying. Is that false positive or am I missing something here?

The static code analysis is giving a suggestion.  It's suggestion does not seem appropriate in this situation.  If you really want to placate the static code analyzer, consider passing void on_message(std::unique_ptr<MyLargeObject> my_large_object_in_a_smart_pointer).

Using a smart pointer will ensure the lifetime of the object, as well as save copying.

I can't change the signature of the callback. Because of that, as far as I know, I can't use a smart pointer to avoid copying.

There is a big difference between passing the object and passing a reference. If the signature is MyLargeObject b then you are passing a full copy on the stack.  Not good. If it is MyLargeObject & b then you are only passing a single pointer. Good.
But... if the object is going to change (or worse yet, get deleted) while running the background task then you must make a copy. It is better is to favor an immutable object style. Can make MyLargeObject read only? Or guarantee it will not change? This feels like a problem that is solved by re-thinking the overall dataflow and context.

I know that the what the static analyzer says is just a suggestion, but I may need to explain why I am ignoring it so I am looking for confirmation for my assumption.

@RichardKeene The only problem/questionis whether there is a way to avoid the copying without changing the callback's signature, which is not an option. It already sounds to me that the answer is no, as I assumed.

Does the referenced large object live at least as long as the async call takes? Can it potentially be changed after the call to on_message returns?

@TedLyngmo There is no guarantee for that. I can't expect it to live longer than until the callback returns.

Ah... ok, if you can't change the signature, then copying it seems like the easy fix.

Correct, if you can not change the outer callback code then you may be just stuck with making a copy and process that. Is there some way to give less data to the outer code, such as if it is an image, reduce the frame rate? Or if it is large DB data, be more selective in the SQL? Is it a color image and you could capture gray scale instead?
Try taking a step back to the larger view and see where you might avoid the large data. "The fastest code is that which is never executed".

Task functor accepting an object by reference seems like a reasonable suggestion. Note that it does not imply that task's shared state should store reference to the object from library callback. Task should create a copy so it survives long enough, however functor should accept a reference to avoid yet another copy when it is invoked.
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

struct Object
{
    Object()
    { ::std::cout << static_cast<void *>(this) << " Object{}\n"; }
    Object(Object const & object)
    { ::std::cout << static_cast<void *>(this) << " Object{copy}" << static_cast<void const *>(&object) <<"\n"; }
    ~Object()
    { ::std::cout << static_cast<void *>(this) << " ~Object\n"; }
};

void ByRef(Object const & object)
{ ::std::cout << static_cast<void const *>(&object) << " ByRef\n"; }
void ByCopy(Object const object)
{ ::std::cout << static_cast<void const *>(&object) << " ByCopy\n"; }
void Callback(Object const & object)
{
    ::std::cout << "ByRef Start\n";
    ::std::async(::std::launch::async, ByRef, object).get();
    ::std::cout << "ByCopy Start\n";
    ::std::async(::std::launch::async, ByCopy, object).get();
}

int main()
{
    Object object{};
    Callback(object);
    ::std::cout << "Done\n";
    return 0;
}

online compiler

0x7ffe6a71789f Object{}
ByRef Start
0x14e6308 Object{copy}0x7ffe6a71789f
0x14e6308 ByRef
0x14e6308 ~Object
ByCopy Start
0x14e6308 Object{copy}0x7ffe6a71789f
0x7149b1bfecc8 Object{copy}0x14e6308
0x7149b1bfecc8 ByCopy
0x7149b1bfecc8 ~Object
0x14e6308 ~Object
Done
0x7ffe6a71789f ~Object

